# Anaconda failing md5 check for update?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm doing `conda update conda` and it is failing with the following error:

```
Error: MD5 sums mismatch for download: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/conda-4.0.4-py35_0.tar.bz2 (d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e != f4763f3ffa7789fee3b8b6287a175771)
```

Looking online it seems like some people have had issues with slow internet, but that's not the problem.  Is this an error on their side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [problem](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/L8U3k4R0CHQ) with conda 4.0.3.
To solve this problem and update to fixed conda version:

1. Run `conda update conda`. It will fail with subj problem, but you will get url for new distribution.
2. Get this url of new conda archive. For me (osx) it was https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/conda-4.0.4-py27_0.tar.bz2
3. Download this file
4. Run `conda install <downloaded file path>`